# NodeJS + Express: How to use sessions variables in other methods. (Session-variable: undefined)

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-variables

I'm using NodeJS 0.10.18 and Express 3.4.0 for a webserver to work with an PhoneGap application.

I want to use Session Variables/Sessions to store the users Username to use it in other methods.

When i login in the login method, the username is stored in *req.session.name* (it **is** set because i can print it to the console). But later on when i want to use it in the reserve method the *req.session.name* variable is suddenly undefined.

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
//NodeJS Modules
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");

//Variables
var app = express();
var listenport = '8123';
var Username = "";
var Password = "";


//Application configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.cookieParser('S3CRE7'));
    app.use(express.cookieSession());
    app.use(app.router);
});


//Create header for every HTTP response
app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
    next();
});

//Login
app.post("/MobileApplication/login", function(req, res) {
    //Response 0 = correct

    var loginUsername = req.param('Username');

    //VALIDATE 

    //STORE IN SESSION
    req.session.name = loginUsername;
    console.log(req.session.name);

    res.end("0");
});


//Reservation
app.post("/MobileApplication/reserve", function(req, res) {
    var name = req.session.name;
    console.log(name);
    res.end("0");
});

//If the url isn't valid respond with 404
app.all("*", function(request, response) {
    response.end("404!");
});

//Listen on listenport
http.createServer(app).listen(listenport);
```

Phonegap ajax login request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://" + serverip + ":" + serverpoort + "/MobileApplication/login?Username=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password + "",
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                console.log("login - sending");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("login - succes!");

                if (data === "0") {
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('#checkbox-1').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            // perform operation for checked
                            window.localStorage.setItem("Username", Username);
                            window.localStorage.setItem("Password", Password);
                            $.mobile.navigate("#customers", {transition: "slide"});
                        }
                        else {
                            // perform operation for unchecked
                            window.localStorage.setItem("Username", "");
                            window.localStorage.setItem("Password", "");
                            $.mobile.navigate("#customers", {transition: "slide"});
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (data === "1") {
                    navigator.notification.alert(
                            'The username you have entered does not exist.', // message
                            doNothing,
                            'Error', // title
                            'Ok'                  // buttonName
                            );
                }
                if (data === "2") {
                    navigator.notification.alert(
                            'You have entered a wrong password.', // message
                            doNothing,
                            'Error', // title
                            'Ok'                  // buttonName
                            );
                }

            },
            error: function(a, b, c) {
                alert("login - error: " + a.toString() + " " + b.toString() + " " + c.toString());
                navigator.notification.alert(
                        "login - error: " + a.toString() + " " + b.toString() + " " + c.toString(), // message
                        doNothing,
                        'Error', // title
                        'Ok'                  // buttonName
                        );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you add the client (Phonegap) code that make the call to the server, I'm guessing that the request doesn't send the session cookie to the server

Comment: Can you log contents of `req.cookies` and check if you're getting `connect` cookie id.

Comment: @IvanFraixedes i have added the ajax request

Comment: I think that that request doesn't send the cookie so phonegap is local application rather than a web application (it doesn't load a web page from a server) so when the server sends the cookie to phonegap, it ignores it, so when next request don't send it. Basically because the cookies only are sent for request to the same domain, it make sense that phonegap doesn't send that cookie, so it is a self contained application. However, I haven't reproduce you code in my dev machine and I inspected my thoughts.

Comment: @vmx i have logged the contents of req.cookies and it's empty and when i try to log the connect ID ( req.sessionID ) it say's undefined.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't you activate the session handler in express by creating a store (or using the default memorystore) and get everything going, set a key etc, as in -> `express.session({ secret: session_secret })` otherwise how would it store the data in Phonegap which doesn't really support cookies ?

Comment: Since phonegap app is not able to send the cookies on its own, you'll need to implement a custom solution, store and and pass session_id as query param in every request. Modify your express session code to base the session object on session_id received in req.query.

Comment: @adeneo I'm testing in a browser (Chrome) so it should work like a webapplication. And i've already tried to add a secret, still didn't work.

Comment: @PeterTielbeek, it confirmed that the cookies aren't sent, so session is empty in each request.